# How to fix OpenCV unable to import in my pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

When I try to run my project in order to read an image, OpenCV shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Krishhnandu\PycharmProjects\test\error.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(cv2.__version__)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: From you error it looks like you're trying to run `print(cv2.__version__)` which won't run because, as the error points out, cv2 doesn't have a `__version__` attribute. What does your code look like?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: im just trying to configure wheather opencv is import on my pycharm. But while im try to read a image its showing opencv import error. My code is : 

import cv2 as cv

img = "Ronaldo-1.jpg"

print(img)

Comment: You are loading the image in a wrong way. You should load your image properly, like this: `img = cv.imread("Ronaldo-1.jpg")` and your image must be inside your project folder path, if you are passing the argument to `cv.imread()` method like that (without any specific path and just by the name of the file).

Answer (score 1):

uninstall opencv using

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

Then reinstall using

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Then use the following command

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```